# Font awesome color won't change on hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have this bit of css that works for changing the cursor when hovering, but not for changing the color.
Why does the cursor change, but not the color?

```
.fa-star-o:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}
```

Here is some html. It looks kinda like this

```
<div id=@Model.ProfileImages.ElementAt(i).BandyProfileImageId class="item profile-image-item">
     <img style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ProfileImages.ElementAt(i).ImageThumbnailCropped)))" alt="no profile images">
     <i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; color: whitesmoke;" class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x trashImage"></i>
     <i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 35px; color: yellow;" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/b22LneLz/

Comment: It is because styles defined inline using `style="..."` override styles defined in any css file. You should consider moving the inline css to a dedicated stylesheet.

Comment: so inline color here overrides a hover? I thought they were different css styles?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are setting the color of the icon with inline styles. These will not be changed by styles in a stylesheet, unless you use `!important`. It works for me if I use this:

```
.fa-star-o:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red !important;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b22LneLz/4/).

That being said, it is better to move all of your inline styling to a stylesheet and avoid using `!important`.

**Edit:** By the way, the reason you want to avoid `!important` when possible is that it can make debugging difficult because CSS is no longer cascading as expected and if you or anyone else wants to override the hover color in the future, you/they will have to use `!important` again and it becomes a vicious cycle.

Comment: yes I see. I just made the change and it works. But now I'm wondering if this will affect any other font awesome icons on other pages?

Comment: @user1186050 This will only affect icons with a class of `.fa-star-o`. By the way, the reason you want to avoid `!important` when possible is that it can make debugging difficult because CSS is no longer cascading as expected and if you or anyone else wants to override the hover color in the future, you/they will have to use `!important` again and it becomes a vicious cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I need the rest of HTML to check it out. However, I have coded a piece of HTML on my own adding your CSS and it worked. Look:

CSS:

```
.fa-star-o:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o">Hi</i>
```

And finally the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b22LneLz/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `inline` styles as everyone says. `Inline` takes precedence over `classes` or `ids` (unless that you add the *!important*). `:hover` is a *pseudoclass* so it takes precedence over `:hover` as well.

Here's a little example so you can see it

```css
.fa-star-o:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}

.stdColor{
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<a class="fa-star-o" style="color: gray" href="www.google.com"> Inline style </a>
</br>
<a class="fa-star-o stdColor"  href="www.google.com"> Not inline style </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write argument "color" in html. As soon as you remove "color: yellow;" from html, everything works fine. Use only css file for the styles like this you won't have problems.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .fa-star-o{color:yellow;}
    .fa-star-o:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x">hi</i> 

(i).BandyProfileImageId class="item profile-image-item">

<img style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ProfileImages.ElementAt(i).ImageThumbnailCropped)))" alt="no profile images">

<i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;" class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x trashImage">hi</i>

<i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 35px; " class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x">hi</i>
```

Comment: the color is not in the html it's in the style. And sure I can! I did! So I'm not sure what your referring too.

Answer (score 0):

Move the link of this CSS file(in which the above CSS is written) to the bottom of other CSS links.

This will work.